# How to prevent apps script from getting very slow after a number of times of deployment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, deployment, web-applications

I've been having this problem with apps script. After modifying the codes and deploying it as new for many times, it would just suddenly get really slow, like just keep loading when I wanted to deploy a newer version. The only solution I knew was to duplicate the Google Sheet and deploy the web app in the newer sheet again. Same codes and everything and it worked. But still problematic.

I just found out that when we want to update the web app, we can go to Manage >> New version, thus getting it updated while keeping the old URL. So I was wondering if I do that, will I be able to avoid the problem of very slow deployment? Sorry for my English, I hope I've made the situation clear. Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will avoid this problem by creating a new version instead of creating a new deployment.

Another simple solution might be to delete the old deployments. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#delete_a_versioned_deployment

Another option is to use CLASP. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/clasp?hl=en#deploy_a_published_project